# Automate BOT that click on a Button after finding a Color

Tags: button, colors, bots

I need a Bot that can click on a specific button after finding a predetermined color.
For example: I have a area 100x100 px with some random colors that changes very fast on the left side and I have a button on the right side. I need that the Bot to detect when that specified color shows up, to click on that button and the process to repeat every time the color appears until I end the process [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BaJH.png). I need to be able to set the position where the Bot to search for color and to set the clicking area. Can I get some help?

Comment: is this a web application that you're trying to automate? you can use Selenium for that

Comment: I am a beginner in programming. I need some code example in python maybe :)

Comment: I don't want to learn from scratch. I need the code only and I will modify it :)